# Possible to retrieve supported resolutions and refresh rates with Nvidia NVAPI?

Tags: winapi, screen-resolution, nvapi

Is it possible to retrieve supported resolutions and refresh rates with Nvidia NVAPI?

I know this is possible with Win32 APIs but I'm wondering if it's possible with NVAPI.